# Use Javascript onClick Event to go to href of a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, location-href

Due some weirdness I'm stuck with using javascript to Jquery to get a link to work by clicking the a parent li element. Basically clicking anywhere on the **li** should take the user to the link of the **a** that is a direct child of it. What I have some far does not seem to work. The code:

```
<ul>
<li onclick="location.href='$(this).children('a:first').attr('href')';">
    <a href="http://example.com/">link</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put single quotes around the href, its seen as a string. Also, you used single quotes within other single quotes, which ends the string prematurely. It literally tries to go to the url "$(this).children(".

Instead, remove the single quotes around the location.href

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="location.href=$(this).children('a:first').attr('href');">
        <a href="http://example.com/">link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also, you really shouldn't use inline scripts like this. It's much better to add a script tag to the bottom of the page and put a script in there that binds to the li's click event.

Answer (score 7):

You could simplify your code by moving not using onclick, but rather using a selector to target that node and have a click event there.

```
$(".myUl li").on("click", function() {
    location.href = $(this).children("a").attr("href");
});
```

But you really should solve this by using css. You can use `display: block;` on the `<a>` as well, and have that fill the content, add extra paddings and basically behave like a div but keep the linking capability.

Comment: Yeah I know this should be a css solution, but the actual page in question has some php that somehow is restricting the links from working normally, so as I'm unable to decipher it, I tried to use JS instead.

Answer (score 1):

replace with this

```
    <li onclick="location.href=$(this).children('a:first').attr('href');">
```